# Winforms open another project from Form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, google-plus

I have an app in WinForms in which I want to open another project from WinForms app.
I also have a login Form and I want to click a button and on that click execute a project with Google+ singing. 
I already have working g+ project and I need to open it with web browser.
I know there's a web control in winforms but I don't think it'll work for me.
 I "combined" two projects in one solution but I don't what's the next thing to do..

Is there any way to do it? Any suggestions on that?

Comment: You don't really "run" projects, you build them and run the output. So if you can find the output folder and whatever output is created from that build, then you can run that. Unless its a web-project and it opens a local website, then there may be some kind of self-hosting server with a command line.

Comment: Yes it is a web project. Thank you, I'll look into that.

Comment: If you want to 'launch' a Form that's in another project, but in the same solution, you can add a reference to the second project in the first, and then call the second project's methods (create an instance of the second form and call `Show()`).